# SVG rects don't appear in Firefox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3.js to create a map from rectangles.

```
svg1.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", function(d, i) {
        for (i=0; i<d.value.length; i++) {
        if (d.value[i].victory == "winner") {
            var winnerRes = d.value[i].result
        };
      }
      if (winnerRes <= 49) { return "color4050" }
      else if (winnerRes >= 50 && winnerRes <= 59) { return "color5060" }
      else if (winnerRes >= 60 && winnerRes <= 69) { return "color6070" }
      else if (winnerRes >= 70 && winnerRes <= 79) { return "color7080" }
      else if (winnerRes >= 80 && winnerRes <= 89) { return "color8090" };
    })
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.value[0].xCoord;
    })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.value[0].yCoord;
    })
```

And it works perfectly in Chrome and Opera, but in Firefox and Explorer SVG rectangles don't appear.
Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/e2b925w2/

Comment: rect elements musst have height and width attributes. Where are yours?

Comment: I'm applying classes to rects in the code above and setting their height and width in the css properties of these classes

Comment: Only Chrome/Opera support that at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the attributes (width and height) using CSS. Apparently, SVG 2 specification will allow attributes to be [defined using CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html), and some browsers are starting to support that, but not all browsers support this yet.

If you set the attributes this way:

```
.attr("width", "28px")
.attr("height", "28px")
```

Your code will work. Here is the fiddle, which works in firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/mk4sxxbp/